# external JavaScript date file

Tags: javascript

So I'm trying to create an external JavaScript file that displays the date in this format;

[Weekday], [Month] [Date] [Year]

I have been looking online (w3schools) and they have given me some really good help, but don't seem to be giving me what I really want to know.

I have tried a few different things, but I don't seem to be getting what I want.

Can anyone link me a website/tutorial, or an actual file that gives me the date in that format?

(I am quite new to all this so I am quite lost :P )

So far this is what I have been working with, but haven't been able to get it to display in my page :(

```
var current_date = new Date ( );

var month_names = new Array ( );
month_names[month_names.length] = "January";
month_names[month_names.length] = "February";
month_names[month_names.length] = "March";
month_names[month_names.length] = "April";
month_names[month_names.length] = "May";
month_names[month_names.length] = "June";
month_names[month_names.length] = "July";
month_names[month_names.length] = "August";
month_names[month_names.length] = "September";
month_names[month_names.length] = "October";
month_names[month_names.length] = "November";
month_names[month_names.length] = "December";

var day_names = new Array ( );
day_names[day_names.length] = "Sunday";
day_names[day_names.length] = "Monday";
day_names[day_names.length] = "Tuesday";
day_names[day_names.length] = "Wednesday";
day_names[day_names.length] = "Thursday";
day_names[day_names.length] = "Friday";
day_names[day_names.length] = "Saturday";

document.write ( day_names[current_date.getDay()] );
document.write ( ", " );
document.write ( month_names[current_date.getMonth()] );
document.write ( " " + current_date.getDate() );
document.write ( " " );
document.write ( " " + current_date.getFullYear() );
```

Comment: Make sure your script is inside the `<body>`.  Also, find a better source of information than [w3schools](http://w3fools.com).

Comment: @Teemu Yeah, I just copied it from where I got it. Coming from the external, I can't seem to pull any information to the page :/

Comment: @Pointy Suggestions? And I had it in an external, so it didn't have any of the <script> tags.

Comment: Have you checked for errors in the browser console? Have you tried using `console.log()` instead of `document.write()`?

Comment: @Pointy I haven't :/ I am trying to make an external js, and link them (month, date, ect) by using document.getElementById() But nothing is coming through

Comment: @Teemu Fixed, and yes, I double checked :(

Comment: [`document.write`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.write) doesn't work on XML pages...?

Comment: @Teemu Maybe I'm just being stupid, but I'm almost positive I am coding my page in HTML

Comment: @Harrison It was just speculation, since there seems to be nothing in your post, which would explain why your code doesn't work : ). I'd suggest you to take a look at the console, and make sure the file really is loaded... You can add an `alert()` or sth to file etc. The code itself should work as it is. Can we see the `script` tag which should load the script?

Comment: @Teemu I know. I just put it in the body of my html and it loads perfectly, but when I try and link it as an external, nothing :/

Comment: Move your script include inside the bottom of the body tag instead of at the top in the head section.

Comment: I got it to work, I'm just going to keep it in the body of my page. Not going to bother with external on this, just going to get me annoyed haha. Thanks for all the help. :)